# How to Change Default Null to NOT NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, default, alter-table

I have the following column in table `room` Now I want to change the definition of column `property_id` from NULL to NOT NULL How can I do this 
following Query is not working

```
ALTER TABLE `room` CHANGE `property_id` `property_id` bigint(20)  NOT NULL;
```

Actual definition of Column is :

```
 `property_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Comment: do you have any rows contain `NULL` before your change the table definition?

Comment: Yes  it have , Should I delete those rows?

Comment: Yes before changing the column condition

Comment: @SFAH You don't need to delete them, per se.  But they cannot be `NULL` when you change the column definition.  What you need to do with your data depends on your data and how you use it.

Comment: @SFAH, then you cannot do that, you have to treat those `NULL` first otherwise if will conflict the column properties

Comment: @Siyual Yes you were Right Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Query was perfectly fine , The only mistake is that there are some rows that contains null record so that why it is creating an issue

Answer (score 3):

In mysql you can achieve this as,

```
ALTER TABLE room MODIFY property_id bigint(20) not null;
```

Comment: In other dbms, such as oracle, it will not allow you alter a nonempty column, but mysql automatically casts things around for you when you alter columns

Comment: @SFAH, But you kept two 'property_id' s in ur query. Check once.